# Regex: Ignoring numbers

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to write a regex that tries to match on a specific string, but ignores all numbers in the target string - So my regex could be 'MyDog', but it should match MyDog, as well as  My11Dog and MyDog1 etc. I could write something like

```
M[^\d]*y[^\d]D[^\d]*o[^\d]g[^\d]*
```

But that is pretty painful. Any ideas out there? I am using Java, and cannot change what is in the string, because I need to retrieve it as is.

Comment: remove the numbers before.

Comment: Which regex tool/language?

Comment: See above - am using java

Comment: or search all `\b[MyDog\d]+\b` and then filter the list.

Comment: Casimir - I don't think that will work. I have to get MyDog, not MgoD

Comment: Should it match `My1D1og1` as well?

Comment: @user2689782: it works, that's why you need to filter the list.

Comment: Yes, any set of numbers within it(or outside it) like MyDog11

Comment: @Casimir, you mean I do 2 regexes? Find everything that has letters MyDog, and then do another regex on that?

Comment: 1) use the regex `\b[MyDog\d]{5,}\b` to find only words that contains only the specific letters and eventually digits. 2) filter the list: test if each item without digits is equal to "MyDog".

Comment: I believe you've answered your own question. Providing the right way and asking for anything but that isn't going to help you more than the regex you've provided.

Comment: Well, my way is really long! Especially as the word gets longer and longer...

Comment: Would it help to generate the regex from a function that takes your string without numbers as input? How long of a string are you talking about?

Comment: as @Reynard suggested: String regexp = "MyDog".replaceAll(".", "$0\\d+");

Comment: Just a note: `[^\d]` is the same as `\D`

Answer (score 5):

Regular Expressions can do this at the end but why don't you get help by your programming language Java? (*I can't Java!*)

```
String s1 = "0My1D2og3";
s2 = s1.replaceAll("\d", "");
if (s2.equals("MyDog")) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I need to use regex because it is a very long file

Comment: @user2689782 Please provide a real world input data.

Comment: As @revo suggested - filter out all digits and use regexp, then instead of equals you can do regexp on output.

Comment: Actually, it's not just digits, but other characters also...so I basically have to go to each word in the file, do filtering, and then move on....